# PHP catching PDO exception

Tags: php, pdo, exception

Why I am getting following error if it's catched?

> Warning: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named
>   Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

```
try {
    $_dbHandler = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$_dbConfig['server']};Database={$_dbConfig['dbName']}", $_dbConfig['username'], $_dbConfig['password']);
    $_dbHandler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $exception) {
    //$exception->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: might be a different kind of Exception

Comment: @DJBurb Could I just catch `Exception` ? Basicly I want to terminate program silently

Comment: I'm under the I'm impression that `catch(Exception $exception)` will catch all exceptions and that `PDOException` is a custom exception that SHOULD be catchable by `Exception` or `PDOException` despite the latter clearly not working for you.

Comment: Perhaps there's an bug in the PHP version you're using. What version is being used? Can you update?

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause can be the namespace: you should try catching `\PDOException` rather than `PDOException`.